# Isolate object with / numpad key Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edit-mode, image

When I hide a mesh by pressing <kbd>Numpad /</kbd>, I isolate the object, but the reference image gets hidden. For some reason my image disappears.
In version 2.7 of Blender I have seen, that the isolate works well with reference images on orthographic mode.
Maybe somewhere in preferences I can find this feature?
Or it is available only in the old version of Blender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The <kbd>/</kbd> key is generating a **Local** (isolated) view of only the selected object, while that in a sense hides other objects, it is more like a isolation chamber rather then hiding all else and then later making things visible again (in the outliner you will see that the other objects are not being hidden).
In **Blender 2.7**, using **Background** images managed in the **Properties panel** opened with <kbd>N</kbd>, found at the bottom, it was possible to have the references still visible in **Local** mode, as those were not managed as objects, but bound to the view.

**Blender 2.8+** deals with **Background** images now by using **empties** to hold the pictures. That makes them objects, which in turn if not selected will be locked out when you have another object selected and go in **Local** mode by pressing <kbd>/</kbd>.

**Solution:**
Keeping the background images visible is possible by simply selecting the images, or their corresponding empties, as well as the object you want to go in **Local** mode with. All selected objects will be taken in **Local** mode and the images will stay visible.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply.But i have separate collection for references background images.I turn off selection for entire collection in order to protect my self from accidentally select and move image. I think it will be kinda annoying each time select image and object to isolate bouth of them.In 2.7 it was so handy when background image stay visible in isolated mode.